# Options for initializing a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

What options do I have when initializing `string[]` object?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

You have several options:

```
string[] items = { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4" };

string[] items = new string[]
{
  "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"
};

string[] items = new string[10];
items[0] = "Item1";
items[1] = "Item2"; // ...
```

Comment: Don't forget the `string[] items = { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4" };` shortcut.

Answer (score 19):

Basic:

```
string[] myString = new string[]{"string1", "string2"};
```

or

```
string[] myString = new string[4];
myString[0] = "string1"; // etc.
```

Advanced: 
From a List

```
list<string> = new list<string>(); 
//... read this in from somewhere
string[] myString = list.ToArray();
```

From StringCollection

```
StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
/// read in from file or something
string[] myString = sc.ToArray();
```

Comment: Can someone add an example of "From a List" above but for the case of loading the contents of 2 lists into a 2 dimensional array (not jagged ie double[,])?

Answer (score 4):

```
string[] str = new string[]{"1","2"};
string[] str = new string[4];
```