# Seperate string insert to array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have string values seperately and want them to insert into an array. For example

```
var Lin1="te1";
var Lin2="te2";
```

I want to insert this into an arry value and want them to use it by array index. ie. for array[0]="te1", array[1]="te2"..

How can we achieve this?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504871/options-for-initializing-a-string-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a List for this, if the number is not known beforehand.

```
 var list = new List<string>() { "te1", "te2"};
 list[0] = "te3";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the contents of an array when you initialise it like so

```
string[] LinArray = new string[] { Lin1, Lin2 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] arr = new string[] {Lin1, Lin2};
```