# Cannot print the foreach value from the custom class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's my code so far

**CUSTOMCLASS.CS**

```
public string[,] tableBR;

string[] strData = {"P  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,P  ,B  ,P  "};

public int X_LENGTH = 104;
public int Y_LENGTH = 15;

#region BR VARIABLES

string BigRD= "";
string[] newBigRD;
string realData= "";

#endregion
public Scoreboard(){
    tableBR= new string[X_LENGTH,Y_LENGTH   ];
}

public void MakeBR(string data){
    BigRD = data;

    for(int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i++){
        BigRD += strData [i];
        BigRD += ",";
    }

    newBigRD= BigRD .Split (',');

    foreach(string newData in newBigRD){
        realData = newData;
    }
}

public string ShowBigRD(){
    return realData;
}

public override string ToString(){
    return "this are all the data :" + realData.ToString();
}
```

And here is my main class

**MAINCLASS.CS**

```
string BigRD= "";

void Start(){
    StartCoroutine ("Win_Log");
}

IEnumerator Win_Log(){
    Scoreboard scoreBoard = new Scoreboard();

    scoreBoard.MakeBR(BigRD);
    Debug.Log ("This is the data : " + scoreBoard.ShowBigRD());

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
}
```

It gives me a null string value . It only prints

> "this are all the data :"

Comment: You realise `strData[]` is initialised with a single element?  What is `realData`?  Looks like you need to step through this to debug.

Comment: realData is overwritten in every iteration of the foreach loop. You also haven't shown us what realData is. What is its type?

Comment: As the others have said, you're overwriting `realData`. Use `+=` instead of just `=`. Or even better, use a string builder

Comment: @AlexK. as far as what I understand sir I pass the value of `BigRD` to `newBigRD` which is I split and i want to display all of what `newBigRd` have so i uses a `for loop` statement where in `newData` is equal to `realData` so that I can return it and get it from my mainclass

Comment: Sorry for the confusion . I incorrectly put the string . I edited it already

Comment: Put the debug.log inside your for each loop, and just run MakeBr. Put the debug after realdata, and use this instead: Debug.Log ("This is the data : " + realdata);

Comment: @TJWolschon What the heck . Sorry about that . I should have used +=

Comment: Why do you think that's a `null`.  It's probably an empty string since you add a comma to the end of `BigRD` so the last item in the loop is going to be an empty string and thus the final value set to `realData`.  The real question is what do you want it to print?

Comment: Should i delete this thread or not ?

Comment: Probably, it's a simple typo so it's unlikely to be useful to future readers. Glad we spotted it though :)

Comment: That's not the only problem with his code though. The foreach is not printing each value. But OP can probably figure that out now.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper It is actually printing all the value

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper b/c it was overwriting them.

Comment: OP wants to print out all the values in one line, or one value per line? I guess it doesn't matter, they solved their problem. Still I don't understand why they use a string[] in the first place if they were just changing it back into a single string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you are looking for this:

```
IEnumerator Win_Log()
{    
    Scoreboard scoreBoard = new Scoreboard();   
    scoreBoard.MakeBigRoad (BigRD);    

    for(int i=0; i< scoreBoard.newBigRD.Length;i++)
    {
        var realData = scoreBoard.newBigRD[i];
        Debug.Log ("This is the data : " + realdata); 
    }

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
}
```

If you decide to do this, you have to make the string[], `string[] newBigRD;` public by changing it to `public string[] newBigRD;`, so it can be accessed outside your class.

You may want to fix you string array declaration too. It should look like this,

```
string[] strData = {"P" ,"B ","B","P","B","B","B","B","B","B","P","P","B","P"};
```

or else we can keep the split method you are using and use

```
newBigRD[]:
```

Which is what I used in my example.

[Options for initializing a string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504871/options-for-initializing-a-string-array)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172106/discussion-on-answer-by-tyler-s-loeper-cannot-print-the-foreach-value-from-the).

Comment: Hey sir . 1 last question

Answer (score 2):

Simple as changing

```
realData = newData;
```

to

```
realData += newData;
```

Otherwise, you're overwriting your `string realData` each time through the loop, instead of just appending it.

Comment: By the way how can i print it one value per line not only 1 line?

Comment: Do what I told you to do in the comments.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper if i don't use a string[] then how can i display them ? i cant use foreach to them . should i use `length`?

Comment: @ChristianTindoc TBH, this should be another question.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper i couldn't write `debug.log`on my custom class you know that sir right?